# jQuery data(): can't get stored data using jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-data

I want to store some information in DOM elements (rows of table). I think I can do it using jQuery's `data()` function. I wrote some test code and found out that I can't get the stored data from elements using jQuery selectors. Is it possible? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Here is the simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery data() test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
    <tr id="rowPrototype" style="display:none;">
        <td class="td1"></td>
        <td class="td2"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    var table = $("#myTable");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var newRow = $("#rowPrototype").clone();
        newRow.removeAttr("style");
        newRow.removeAttr("id");

        $.data(newRow, "number", i);
        console.log("Data added to row: " + $.data(newRow, "number"));

        var tds = newRow.find("td");
        tds.text("test");
        table.append(newRow);
    }

    var trs = table.find("tr");
    trs.each(function () {
        var tr = $(this).text();
        var data = $.data(tr, "number");
        console.log("number: " + data);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect the following output:

```
number: undefined (row prototype)
number: 0
number: 1
number: 2
number: 3
number: 4
```

But actual is:

```
number: undefined
number: undefined
number: undefined
number: undefined
number: undefined
number: undefined
```

So what's wrong with this code?

**UPD**
You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/rfrz332o/3/

Comment: P.S. I know that using jquery-latest link is a bad practice. It's just for example.

Comment: It is advisable that you provide with a working jsFiddle

Comment: @Itay ok, I added the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.data()` expects an actual DOM element as the first argument, not a jQuery object.  You can `$(selector).data()` with jQuery objects.  I'd suggest you change this:

```
$.data(newRow, "number", i);
console.log("Data added to row: " + $.data(newRow, "number"));
```

to this:

```
newRow.data("number", i);
console.log("Data added to row: " + newRow.data("number"));
```

And, then change this:

```
var trs = table.find("tr");
trs.each(function () {
    var tr = $(this).text();
    var data = $.data(tr, "number");
    console.log("number: " + data);
});
```

to this:

```
table.find("tr").each(function () {
    console.log("number: " + $(this).data("number"));
});
```

Comment: About the first (logging data after storing it): it worked fine without this change, but I think it's better your way. And about second, now it works fine, thank you!

Comment: Fix: I understand now that my way to store data in element wasn't right too, so both of these changes are necessary

Answer (score 1):

[`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data) expects `DOM` element, not jQuery object. Add `[i]` or use `.get(i)` at `$.data(newRow[i], "number", i);` and all `js` that follows where `$.data()` is used to reference `DOM` element.

There is also an issue with the `for` loop. If there is actually only one `tr` element and two `td` elements within `#myTable`, when `i` reaches `2` , if the selector included `i` the result would be `undefined`, as the maximum index of `td` elements would still be `1` within the cloned `table` ; whether `$.data()` or `.data()` is used. Similarly for the one `tr` element within `#myTable`; when `i` reaches `1`

> `jQuery.data( element, key, value )`
>
> element
>
> Type: Element
>
> The DOM element to associate with the data.

Comment: @coolguy Are there actually only two `td` elements within `#myTable` ?

Answer (score 1):

You messed with `data` method. You weren't applying data to dynamic created row. To see result, please check your console.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery data() test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
    <tr id="rowPrototype" style="display:none;">
        <td class="td1"></td>
        <td class="td2"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    var table = $("#myTable");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var newRow = $("#rowPrototype").clone();
        newRow.removeAttr("style");
        newRow.removeAttr("id");

        newRow.data("number", i);
        console.log("Data added to row: " + newRow.data("number"));

        var tds = newRow.find("td");
        tds.text("test");
        table.append(newRow);
    }

    var trs = table.find("tr");
    trs.each(function () {
        var tr = $(this).text();
        var data = $(this).data("number")
        console.log("number: " + data);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```